# Failed to load bundle with aws-sdk for react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk

After installing aws-sdk for react native and adding:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');
```

to one of the screens, my app bundle loads up to 99%, freezes and then I get the following error:

```
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Could not connect to development server.

Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate
- WiFi is enabled and connected to the same network as the Node Server
```

...

also this error message appears in my Xcode terminal:

```
Call retries were exceeded aws react native
```

How to fix this bug?

from my package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc": "^1.0.8",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.689.0",
        "events": "^3.1.0",
        "react": "16.11.0",
        "react-native": "0.62.2",
         ...
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2506#issuecomment-549734560) discussing 'failed to load bundle' error with aws-sdk. [This comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2506#issuecomment-549734560) helped me fix this issue:

> I fixed this memory issue in my project with below steps. React-Native
>   : 0.60.5 aws-sdk: 2.398.0
>
> In your package.json add below line in a scripts, "start-max": "node
>   --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
>
> Restart your npm with below command npm run start-max

In my case max-old-space-size=8192 was not enough. I bumped it up to 1600:

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start-max": "node --max-old-space-size=16000 node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
```

I don't know how hacky/stable this fix is but now I can load the app bundle on my iOS device.

Comment: I have been spending 2 days trying to get mine to work as I was constantly getting an error `Could not connect to the development server` this works. Thank you!